# Error Converting VB.NET to C# : obj' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I try to convert vb.net code to c# like below
**VB.NET**

```
  Dim _obj As Object = _srv.GetData(_criteria)
            If _obj IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each Comp As ComponentItem In DirectCast(DirectCast(_obj("ComponentInformation"), Result).Output, List(Of ComponentItem))
                    _lstComp.Add(New Core.Component() With {.ComponentID = Comp.BusinessUnitID, .ComponentName = Comp.BusinessUnitName})
                Next
            End If
```

**C#**

```
   object obj = srv.GetData(criteria);
          if (obj != null)
          {
    foreach (ComponentItem comp in (List<ComponentItem>)((Result)obj("ComponentInformation")).Output)
                  {
                      lstComp.Add(new Component
                      {
                          ComponentId = comp.BusinessUnitID,
                          ComponentName = comp.BusinessUnitName
                      });
                  }
}
```

after converting the code i got an error **obj' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'** How to reslove this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj` is probably an array, in C# you have to access its members via square brackets `[]`. So it should be:

```
obj["ComponentInformation"]
```

**EDIT:** (courtesy [@Groo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69809/groo))

You have to change your line:

```
object obj = srv.GetData(criteria);
```

Instead of `object` you should specify the type which is being returned by the method. Or you can use [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) to have an implicitly typed variable.

```
var obj = srv.GetData(criteria);
```

Comment: i try this but i got error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @JEMI, what does your method `srv.GetData` returns, instead of object you specify that type while define `obj`

Comment: Replacing `object` with `var` in the first line would probably fix the error (unless `GetData` really returns an `object` and you actually need to cast to a indexable class).

Answer (score 1):

Change `object` to `var`:

```
var obj = srv.GetData(criteria);
```

And ...

```
For Each Comp As ComponentItem In DirectCast(DirectCast(_obj["ComponentInformation"], Result).Output, List(Of ComponentItem))
```

Comment: i try this but i got error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Why type does srv.GetData(criteria); return? maybe change it to: var obj = srv.GetData(criteria);

Comment: @DaveBish: `Object`, obviously.

Comment: @Dennis: why would you assume that? Every class is derived from `object` in C#.

Comment: @Dave: I think you've mixed up some VB.NET and C# syntax together. :)

Comment: @Groo: look at `Dim _obj As Object` line, please. Although, you're right - it's a variable type, not a method's return value type.

Answer (score 0):

C#, prior to v 4.0, where `dynamic`s were introduced, doesn't support late binding, like VB does:

```
_obj("ComponentInformation")
```

So, you can't just write something like this for variable of `object` type:

```
_obj["ComponentInformation"]
```

in C# without `dynamic` or reflection API (e.g., if you working with COM object).

You either have to declare variable of appropriate type (which has indexer), or use `dynamic`, or use reflection API.